# Is element in field $F^n$ scalar or vector

Tags: vector-spaces

I am confused about some concepts regarding vector fields.

In the textbook used in my class, it introduces that elements of field denoted as $F$ are called scalars. However, it also mentions something as "a vector in $F^n$". So are elements in $F^n$ scalar or vector?

Suppose that $F^n = \{(x_1, ... ,x_n) \ |\ x_j\in F\ \text{for} \ j = 1,...,n\}$.
The elements are in the form of $(x_1, ...x_n)$ right? And are they scalars or vectors?

Comment: They are vectors.  Scalars are just elements of $F$ itself.

Comment: If $n>1$, $F^n$ is not a field.

Comment: It says elements of $F$ are scalars and elements of $F^n$ are vectors. In other words, it answers your question. So where's the issue?

Comment: Intuitively, you can think of scalars as just numbers (0, -15, 2/3, $\pi$, etc). Vectors are numbers *with direction*. Think of an arrow of length 1 starting at the origin pointing to the right (in $\mathbb{R}^2$). This would be the vector (1,0).